# Password database: saving and loading encrypted files

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm writing a password manager application, mostly with the goal of learning about proper handling of encryption.

Here is my code responsible for encrypting/decrypting passwords and loading to/from file. The `PasswordDataBase` class is pretty bare as is, but will incorporate more functionality going further (such as filtering records based on name or tags). I just want to make sure this more sensitive aspect of the code is done right before building upon it.

**Dependencies:** this code depends on the `pyaes` module, which you can find [on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyaes/).

passworddb.py:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from hashlib import scrypt
import pickle
import secrets
from typing import List
import uuid

import pyaes


class InvalidPasswordException(Exception):
    pass


class PasswordDataBase:

    SALT_LENGTH = 16

    @dataclass
    class Record:
        name: str = field(default='')
        login: str = field(default='')
        password: str = field(default='')
        uid: uuid.UUID = field(default_factory=uuid.uuid4)
        tags: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __init__(self):
        self.records = []

    def save_to_file(self, path: str, password: str):
        """
        Save the current instance to a file.

        Parameters
        ----------
        path : str
            Path of the file to save.
        password : str
            The master password used for encryption.

        Returns
        -------
        None.
        """
        password = bytes(password, encoding='utf-8')
        salt = secrets.token_bytes(self.SALT_LENGTH)
        key = scrypt(password,
                     n=2**14,
                     r=8,
                     p=1,
                     salt=salt,
                     dklen=32)
        cipher = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR(key)

        with open(path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(salt)
            file.write(cipher.encrypt(pickle.dumps(self)))

    @classmethod
    def load_from_file(cls, path: str, password: str):
        """
        Load an encrypted password database from a file.

        Parameters
        ----------
        path : str
            Path to the file to load.
        password : str
            Master password used to decrypt the file.

        Raises
        ------
        InvalidPasswordException
            The provided password was invalid.

        Returns
        -------
        PasswordDataBase
            A PasswordDatabase instance containing the decrypted data.
        """
        password = bytes(password, encoding='utf-8')
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            salt = file.read(cls.SALT_LENGTH)
            data = file.read()

        key = scrypt(password,
                     n=2**14,
                     r=8,
                     p=1,
                     salt=salt,
                     dklen=32)
        cipher = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR(key)
        try:
            return pickle.loads(cipher.decrypt(data))
        except pickle.UnpicklingError as error:
            raise InvalidPasswordException("Invalid password") from error


def generate_password(length: int, charset: str) -> str:
    """
    Generate a securely random password.

    Parameters
    ----------
    length : int
        Generated password length.
    charset : str
        Allowable characters for password generation.

    Returns
    -------
    str
        The generated password.
    """
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(charset) for _ in range(length))
```

passworddb_tests.py:

```py
"""
Unit tests for the password_manager modules
"""

import os
from string import ascii_letters, digits, punctuation
import tempfile
import unittest

from passworddb import (PasswordDataBase,
                        InvalidPasswordException,
                        generate_password)


ALL_CHARS = ascii_letters + digits + punctuation


class PasswordDataBaseTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_roundtrip(self):
        """
        Verify that a password database written to a file is correctly
        recovered upon loading.
        """
        original = PasswordDataBase()
        original.records.append(
            PasswordDataBase.Record(name='foo',
                                    login='bar',
                                    password=generate_password(64, ALL_CHARS)))
        original.records.append(
            PasswordDataBase.Record(name='ga',
                                    login='bu',
                                    password=generate_password(64, ALL_CHARS),
                                    tags=['zo', 'meu']))
        original.records.append(PasswordDataBase.Record())
        password = "Secr3t"

        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
            path = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'test')
            original.save_to_file(path, password)
            recovered = PasswordDataBase.load_from_file(path, password)

        for expected, actual in zip(original.records, recovered.records):
            self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_roundtrip_empty(self):
        """
        Verify that an empty password database written to a file is correctly
        recovered upon loading.
        """
        original = PasswordDataBase()
        password = "Secr3t"

        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
            path = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'test')
            original.save_to_file(path, password)
            recovered = PasswordDataBase.load_from_file(path, password)

        for expected, actual in zip(original.records, recovered.records):
            self.assertEqual(expected, actual)


    def test_load_fails_with_wrong_password(self):
        """
        Ensure that records written to a file can't be recovered using an
        incorrect password.
        """
        database = PasswordDataBase()
        database.records.append(
            PasswordDataBase.Record(name='foo',
                                    login='bar',
                                    password=generate_password(64, ALL_CHARS)))
        database.records.append(
            PasswordDataBase.Record(name='ga',
                                    login='bu',
                                    password=generate_password(64, ALL_CHARS),
                                    tags=['zo', 'meu']))
        database.records.append(PasswordDataBase.Record())

        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
            path = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'test')
            database.save_to_file(path, 'right')
            self.assertRaises(InvalidPasswordException,
                              lambda: PasswordDataBase.load_from_file(path, 'wrong'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

My main concerns are:

- Does this code follow best practices when it comes to security?
- Is the test coverage good enough? I feel like it could be improved, but I find it hard to come up with additional meaningful tests.

Any other remarks about my code are also welcome, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this code follow best practices when it comes to security?

No.

This is [SOTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_the_art)
from a few decades ago.

Passwords have low entropy, typically much less than 256 bits.
Modern implementations will prefer to frustrate an attacker
by using a deliberately slow password stretcher, such as
[argon2id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).
Even with that, if the end user chose a word from a
dictionary that the attacker has, or chose a word
that a simple generator is likely to stumble upon,
then there's no saving the scheme.
Argon2 merely slows down such an attack,
making it take much longer to succeed.

---

## partial type annotation

Consider telling `mypy` that `save_to_file` returns `-> None:`

Not sure why your docstring
[redundantly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
mentions types, since the signature already revealed them.

The `... , path: str, ...` is nice enough,
but declaring it `path: Path` would be nicer,
more informative.

```
        password = bytes(password, encoding='utf-8')
```

Consider assigning to `password1` here, or some other identifier.
Yes, python lets you dynamically change type.
But that tends to make it harder to reason about the code.
*This* bit of code is trivial, it's no big deal,
but when a conditional changes the type for some inputs yet not all,
that leads to complexity and bugs.
It's just a habit, preserving type stability, that you may want to get into.

Kudos on using a `with` context manager when you open a file for writing.

---

## pickle

```
            file.write(cipher.encrypt(pickle.dumps(self)))
```

This is convenient.
There's nothing wrong with it, exactly.
But consider using a stable pack / unpack approach to serialization.

Too often I have written a pickle using library v2,
then it revs to v3, and I see unpickle fail :-(
Data files often last longer than a public API will.

---

## tests

I imagine your tests achieve good code coverage. Verify by using
[pytest --cov](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cov).
There's probably one or two error cases you've not exercised.
And you know what they say, "A line of code that never ran
is likely a buggy line."

The notion of round-tripping is very nice.
You can think of it as an oracle,
which can tell whether the right thing happened.
This is the perfect setup for my favorite advanced testing library:
[hypothesis](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis).
Let it torture test your code for a bit,
looking for edge cases like "empty passphrase",
"super long passphrase", "passphrase that tries to use unicode characters",
and so on. You have already written some nice target code
that checks for such things, but you'd be surprised
what hypothesis may manage to dig up.
Certainly it has surprised me when I ran it against my own code.

---

This code accomplishes a subset of its design goals.
It should not be merged down to `main` until it adopts
a "slow" password stretcher such as `argon2id`.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks
on this codebase.